# How to calucate the number of steps in interative exponent

Tags: python-3.x

```
def exp2(a,b):
    if b == 1:
        return a
    else: return a*exp2(a,b-1)
```

I want to calucate the number of the program. Accodring to my textbook, I attached how to calucate steps.

> t(b) = 3 + t(b-1) = 3 + 3 + t(b-2) = 3k + t(b-k)

if it's done b-k=1 k=b-1

> t(b) = 3(b-1) + 2 = 3b -1

I can't understand why the first number is 3. How can I get the number 3 in the beginning?

Comment: exp2(a,b) should compute a^b. Maybe there's a typo/something missing in your textbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> step 1: b == 1
>
> step 2: a*exp2
>
> step 3: b-1

The first round is 3, so you can get t(b) = 3 + t(b-1).